# Setting dscp value to socket using setsockopt()

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

Socket options can be set using setsockopt() function. 
The corresponding options are present in the below link:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt

Does this API allow to set the dscp value for the socket?
I don't find any such option in above link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most socket options are defined in other manual pages -- generally in section 7.

See the `ip(7)` man page https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip -- you would use `IPPROTO_IP/IP_TOS` in the `setsockopt`.

Also, that page references a "protocol-independent" way from `socket(7)` https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket (`SOL_SOCKET/SO_PRIORITY`).

Not sure there is anything to recommend one over the other -- it's unlikely you'll be using an underlying protocol that isn't IP.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time finding out how to do this, until I finally stumbled upon [this page](https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-dev/2014-February/280559.html).

For IPv4, you need to use IPPROTO_IP/IP_TOS, and for IPv6 you need to use IPPROTO_IPV6/IPV6_TCLASS. You also need to pass in the DSCP value bit shifted to the left 2 places, since DSCP is a 6 bit field, but IP_TOS and IPV6_TCLASS are 8 bit fields.